# Reseller prices for individualisation

Tags: price, configuration

I've the following problem:

I've a product and I've defined a price for 'normal buyers' and one for 'logged in people' which is the group of re-sellers. The resellers get a special price, which is working.
But now there are some products which you can config and make the product more expensvie.

If a reseller is logged in and buys a product, he gets is to the cheaper re-seller-price, but if he adds a special configuration to the product this config has the 'normal' price.

Can I define a 'reseller-price' for the different configurations anywehere???

Answer (score 0):

You can define a catalog price rule or cart rule to discount products and orders. Or you install something like `Simple configurable Products` to use the prices of the simple items. But I'm not sure, whether the group prices are implemented.

Beside this, how did you implement the cheaper price? If you used customer group prices, this shouldn't happen!